# React - hook useEffect - 'return function' cleaning

Tags: reactjs, return

According to React documentation: useEffect's return is executed **when the component is unmounted**, but my question is: **which component?** : the component where useEffect is declared?, the child component?, ...

Two examples:

In this [article](https://caelinsutch.medium.com/react-useeffect-hook-in-depth-dc6b7c6132e5) **useEffect and its return, was defined** **in the** **child component** 'Simple', and when the useEffect's return is executed, that 'Simple' child component is unmounted. (Component where useEffect is defined, is unmounted)

In this other code, **useEffect and its return, was defined in the parent component** 'RelojHooks', and the component which is unmounted is the child component 'Reloj'. (Component where useEffect is NOT defined, is unmounted)

Parent Component RelojHooks:

```html
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Reloj from './Reloj';


export default function RelojHooks() {

    const [hora, setHora] = useState(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());

    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);


    useEffect(() => {

        let temporizador;

        if (visible) {
            temporizador = setInterval(() => setHora(new Date().toLocaleTimeString()), 1000);
        }
        
        return () => clearInterval(temporizador);

    }, [visible]);


    return (
        <>
            <h2>Reloj con Hooks</h2>
            {visible && <Reloj hora={hora} />}
            <button onClick={() => setVisible(true)}>iniciar</button>
            <button onClick={() => setVisible(false)}>detener</button>
        </>
        
    );
}
```

Child Component Reloj:

```html
export default function Reloj({ hora }) {
    return (
        <h3>{hora}</h3>
    );
}
```

Comment: its always executed when the component in which the `useEffect` was declared dismounts

Comment: Tobias S: thanks for your answer, but I think it's not exactly as you said. For instance: in previous example 2, useEffect is declared in RelojHooks component, and useEffect there is called but that component RelojHooks never unmounts. By the way I was asking about which component is the one that unmounts when useEffect's return is executed.

Comment: is `useEffect` called there or the return function?

Comment: useEffect is called in both cases. First is called when  RelojHooks component is mounted: 'if sentence' . And later useEffect's return is called: when 'visible' variable is set to false. But when useEffect's return is called, RelojHooks component is NOT unmounted: the only one that is unmounted is the child component Reloj.

Comment: @KevinFlynn It's hard to understand what you're asking. Please come up with an example that shows what you are saying. Your existing code doesn't unmount anything. Consider creating a link to https://codepen.io/team/codepen/pen/MLPwqV

Comment: Juan Mendes: the code I wrote does really unmount a component: the child one: Reloj. If you don't believe me try it on React. When 'visible' variable is set to false, useEffect's return at component RelojHooks is called, and at that point child component Reloj is unmounted. But parent component RelojHooks is NOT unmounted. And there is my question: if according to React documentation, useEffect's return is executed when the component is unmounted, why the component RelojHooks is NOT unmounted 
 if it's useEffect's return was executed?

Comment: https://codepen.io/kevin-flynn/pen/NWXBZVg